# Select all elements between two known elements by CSS selector

Tags: css-selectors

I have two elements with defined ids having any html between them, for example:

```
<div id='d1'>Hello</div>

<!-- Here come any html code -->
<div>Example</div><hr/><a href="">Example</a>

<div id='d2'>World</div>
```

Is there CSS selector that selects all the elements between #d1 and #d2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: No.

But you always have the option of JQuery:

```
$('#id').nextUntil('#id2')
```

Keep in mind, the `.nextUntil` method selects all elements in between, *exclusive.* To select the elements including the two elements, use this:

```
$('#id').nextUntil('#id2').andSelf().add('#id2')
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.siblings * { 
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid lightgrey;
    color: lightgrey;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 15px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li.start").nextUntil("li.stop").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
  
    $("li.start1").nextUntil("li.stop1").andSelf().add("li.stop1").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Just selecting all elements in between, exclusive.</p>
  
<div style="width:500px;" class="siblings">
  <ul>ul (parent)  
    <li>li (sibling)</li>
    <li>li (sibling)</li>
    <li class="start">li (sibling with class name "start")</li>
    <li>li (the next sibling of li with class name "start")</li>
    <li>li (the next sibling of li with class name "start")</li>
    <li>li (the next sibling of li with class name "start")</li>
    <li class="stop">li (sibling with class name "stop")</li>
  </ul>   
</div>
  
  <p>Just selecting all elements in between, inclusive.</p>
  
<div style="width:500px;" class="siblings">
  <ul>ul (parent)  
    <li>li (sibling)</li>
    <li>li (sibling)</li>
    <li class="start1">li (sibling with class name "start")</li>
    <li>li (the next sibling of li with class name "start")</li>
    <li>li (the next sibling of li with class name "start")</li>
    <li>li (the next sibling of li with class name "start")</li>
    <li class="stop2">li (sibling with class name "stop")</li>
  </ul>   
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In my opinion, that's the easiest option.

Comment: *"you always have the option of JQuery"* - "**always...**" more like never at this point of the web (2020)

Comment: @vsync jQuery is still awesome, even 5 years later.

Comment: many web apps today run on React / Angular / vue and other lesser-used ones, and most of jQuery users are wordpress websites, which are very much the majority still, but the statement that you can **always** use jQuery isn't not so true, because if you work for a company that uses a framework such as describe above, then you cannot. So the word "always" is not true, more like "probably", but that depends on the product architecture. You cannot simply import jQuery to a React project, that is bad.

Comment: @vsync Definitely agree, but if you need jQuery in a React project, then you're doing something wrong. But importing jQuery into a standard webpage for simple DOM manipulation without having to go through the hassle of setting up React/Angular/etc is still a viable option, I would think.

Comment: Personally I love jQuery, it's a collection of well-written extremely handy functions, which are much easier to work with than native DOM. React apps don't need direct DOm access, don't need the event binding and not the Ajax methods...so basically nothing is left for jQuery to add to those apps.

Comment: I am downoting the answer, because in 2023 there is a way to achieve the result without jQuery, but this answer is still shown as the right one.

Answer (score 3):

I am kind of a newbie in the questions related to CSS, but I was trying to find an answer to the same question and it looks like there is a way to achieve it without jQuery:

```html
#d1~:not(#d2, #d2~*)
```

I am attaching a simple html page to test this solution. WARNING! The snippet uses `alert` to show the result of the selection.

```js
let selectionQuery = document.querySelectorAll("#d1~:not(#d2, #d2~*)");

let selectedElementsCount = selectionQuery.length;
for (let selectedElementIndex = 0; selectedElementIndex < selectedElementsCount; selectedElementIndex++) {
  let tempElement = selectionQuery[selectedElementIndex]
  alert("tempElement.outerHTML: " + tempElement.outerHTML);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <head>
        <title>Select everything between #d1 and #d2</title>
    </head>

    <body>
  

        <span>Something which shouldn't be chosen, because it's before the 1st element</span>

        <div id='d1'>Hello</div>
        
        <!-- Here come any html code -->
        <div>Example</div><hr/><a href="">Example</a>

        <img src="http://some.image.com"/>

        <div id='d2'>World</div>

        <span>Other text which sholdn't be chosen, because it's after the last element</span>
    </body>

</html>
```

If the solution indeed, does what you originally was asking for, then I think it would be right to choose the new right answer to your question (because I and thousands of other devs were looking for the same question and they only saw the 1st answer saying that it's not possible).

Comment: Yes this works well and only uses CSS so up-voting. Using the [subsequent-sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Subsequent-sibling_combinator) from `#d1` but excluding `#d2` and then also excluding any subsequent-sibling combinator from `#d2` onwards is a great solution. The use of [:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) is perfect as it accepts a complex list of exclusions so can be extended. However, this was [blogged](https://css-tip.com/select-elements-between-two-class/) by @TemaniAfif already.