# CSS/SCSS rules for representing different level content of a post

Tags: css-selectors, css-position

I plan to use shift amount to represent the structure of a post consisting of different level content. The deeper the content is, the more the content is shifted right.
For example,

```
<h1>Part1</h1>
This is a post about Universe.

<h2>Part1.1</h2>
First we talk about the Galaxy.

Facts about the Galaxy.
Now you know the Galaxy.

<h3>Part1.1.1</h3>
More details about the Galaxy.

<h2>Part1.2</h2>
Facts aoubt another galaxy.

<h1>Part2</h1>
```

I want the is no padding before `This is a post about Universe.`, a 100px padding for `<h2>Part....you know the Galaxy`, a 200px padding for `<h3>....details about the Galaxy.`. I think css/sass can do this, but I don't know how to choosing thde corresponding elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example, applied to your markup:

```css
h2 {
  padding: 100px 0;
}
h3 {
  padding: 200px 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Part1</h1>
This is a post about Universe.

<h2>Part1.1</h2>
First we talk about the Galaxy.

Facts about the Galaxy.
Now you know the Galaxy.

<h3>Part1.1.1</h3>
More details about the Galaxy.

<h2>Part1.2</h2>
Facts aoubt another galaxy.

<h1>Part2</h1>
```

Comment: No, you misunderstand the question. I also need the content between headers have a padding before them.

Answer (score 0):

You need the use some element like div.

You can check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kh50e9nz/

```
h2, h2 + * {padding-left:100px;}
h3, h3 + * {padding-left:200px;}
```

Comment: It doesn't work If I have two divs under the h2 tag. https://jsfiddle.net/kh50e9nz/6/

Comment: so if you have two divs under the h2 tag,  
h2, h2 + *, h2 + * + * {padding-left:100px;}

Comment: The number of divs under the h2 tag is not fixed. I want to write a css/sass rule to apply to these situations no matter how many divs under the h2 tag. Maybe I have to use JQuery according to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035432/select-all-elements-between-two-known-elements-by-css-selector)

Comment: So the key is the `~` selector. But it's not enough because for a expression `a ~ b` it doesn't require the precedence to be the closest _a_ element before _b_ . If we only have a limited number of CSS rules like `path ~ b`, when there are such many elements before the _b_ element that any `path ~ b` rule can be applied, then the result just depends on the last rule. That's not the result I want. This is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/kh50e9nz/9/).