# Select css siblings between two elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, queryselector

The html I'm looking at looks like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('h4#unique_id  ~ h5 ~p +p +h5').forEach(title => console.log(title))
```

```html
<body>
  <h4 id="unique_id"> foo bing bar </h4>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <!-- selection should start here -->
    <h5>title text 1</h5>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <h5>title text 2</h5>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <h5>title text 3</h5>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
  <!-- and end here -->
  <h4 id="randome_id_234353">title text</h4>
  <p>some text I don't want</p>
  <p>some text I don't want</p>
  <h5>title text I don't want</h5>
  <p>some text I don't want</p>
  <h5>title text I don't want</h5>
  <p>some text I don't want</p>
  <h5>title text I don't want</h5>
  <p>some text I don't want</p>
</body>
```

I want to grab all the `h5` elements, and if possible the `p` elements as well.

I have `document.querySelectorAll('h4#unique_id  ~ h5 ~p +p +h5')` so far but that misses the first `h5` I want and grabs the last one I don't want. I can't figure out sibling selectors or how to use `:not` or similar to stop when I find another `h4`.

This question [Select all elements between two known elements by CSS selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035432/select-all-elements-between-two-known-elements-by-css-selector) relies on jquery which I don't have access to, and [Select elements between two defined elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61048879/select-elements-between-two-defined-elements) relies on knowning the number and position of elements, which I don't.

Is this possible with just css selectors?

Comment: Do you mean you want to grab all the h5 elements and all p elements that come after the very first h4 but you don't want to grab anything that comes after the second h4?

Comment: Further to A Haworth's question, could you post the code with, for example, an HTML comment showing `<!-- selection should start here --> .... <!-- and end here -->`, just to be explicit about what you're trying to select?

Comment: @AHaworth yes, see my edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok you can use a mixture of sibling selector and not:

The selector is:

```css
#unique_id~p:not(#unique_id~h4~p) /* any p following the unique id but not a p following another h4 after the unique id */
```

you then repeat this selector for your h5s and the result is:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#unique_id~p:not(#unique_id~h4~p),#unique_id~h5:not(#unique_id~h4~h5)').forEach(title => title.style.color = 'red');
```

```html
<h4 id="unique_id"> foo bing bar </h4>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<h5>title text 1</h5>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<h5>title text 2</h5>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<h5>title text 3</h5>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<h4 id="randome_id_234353">title text</h4>
<p>some text I don't want</p>
<p>some text I don't want</p>
<h5>title text I don't want</h5>
<p>some text I don't want</p>
<h5>title text I don't want</h5>
<p>some text I don't want</p>
<h5>title text I don't want</h5>
<p>some text I don't want</p>
```

As per your edit - not to include the p before the first h5 (selector is slightly modified from Alohci's comment):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#unique_id~:is(h5, h5~p):not(#unique_id ~ h4 ~ *)').forEach(title => title.style.color = 'red');
```

```html
<h4 id="unique_id"> foo bing bar </h4>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<h5>title text 1</h5>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<h5>title text 2</h5>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<h5>title text 3</h5>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
<h4 id="randome_id_234353">title text</h4>
<p>some text I don't want</p>
<p>some text I don't want</p>
<h5>title text I don't want</h5>
<p>some text I don't want</p>
<h5>title text I don't want</h5>
<p>some text I don't want</p>
<h5>title text I don't want</h5>
<p>some text I don't want</p>
```

Comment: Nice, though it might be worth using `h4[id^=unique_id` and `h4[id^=randome_id]` (assuming that those elements follow some predictable pattern).

Comment: Or you could combine the two parts with `#unique_id~:is(h5, p):not(#unique_id ~ h4 ~ *)`

Comment: nice use of `is` and more readable selector

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. If I understand your problem correctly, you want to log all of the elements that are not containing `some text I don't want` and the `h5`-elements.

If you have a parent element, you can use the `>` to selector in combination with the parent element to select all of its children with the `*`-selector.

You can apply multiple `:not()`-selectors to a statement. Below I just selected all `p` and `h4`-elements that are preceded by the `h4#randome_id_234353`-element, like so:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.container > *:not(h4#randome_id_234353 ~ p):not(h4#randome_id_234353 ~ h5):not(h4)').forEach(title => console.log(title))
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h4 id="unique_id"> foo bing bar </h4>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <h5>title text 1</h5>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <h5>title text 2</h5>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <h5>title text 3</h5>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <h4 id="randome_id_234353">title text</h4>
  <p>some text I don't want</p>
  <p>some text I don't want</p>
  <h5>title text I don't want</h5>
  <p>some text I don't want</p>
  <h5>title text I don't want</h5>
  <p>some text I don't want</p>
  <h5>title text I don't want</h5>
  <p>some text I don't want</p>
</div>
</body>
```

If you don't have a container, you can use the same logic to `log` everything that does **not** preceed `h4#randome_id_234353`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('h4#unique_id ~ *:not(h4#randome_id_234353 ~ *):not(h4#randome_id_234353)').forEach(title => console.log(title))
```

```html
<body>
  <h4 id="unique_id"> foo bing bar </h4>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <h5>title text 1</h5>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <h5>title text 2</h5>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <h5>title text 3</h5>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <h4 id="randome_id_234353">title text</h4>
  <p>some text I don't want</p>
  <p>some text I don't want</p>
  <h5>title text I don't want</h5>
  <p>some text I don't want</p>
  <h5>title text I don't want</h5>
  <p>some text I don't want</p>
  <h5>title text I don't want</h5>
  <p>some text I don't want</p>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't have a container element though

Comment: fair, I edited the answer and applied the same logic just not with the container. it selects everything that doesn't preceed `h4#randome_id_234353` + the `h4`-element itself @AncientSwordRage

Answer (score 1):

Only a small number of array methods work with array-like objects, so I often find it useful to turn a `NodeList` (which is an *iterable, array-like object* but, crucially, **not** an `array`) into an `array`, so that I can do *many more* things with it.

In this case by turning `NodeList` into an `array` I can use the javascript method `.filter()` which is exactly what I need to remove the unwanted elements from the end of the collection.

---

### Turning a `NodeList` into an `array`:

How can I turn this `static NodeList`:

```
let myClassElements = document.querySelectorAll('.myclass');
```

into an `array`?

By combining `spread syntax` (`...`) with an `array literal` (`[]`):

```
let myClassElements = [... document.querySelectorAll('.myclass')];
```

---

On that basis, I can create an `array` of all the elements I do need (plus a few unnecessary ones):

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('h4#unique_id ~ h5, h4#unique_id ~ p')]
```

and also another array of all the unnecessary elements:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('h4:not(#unique_id) ~ h5, h4:not(#unique_id) ~ p')]
```

And then I can `.filter()` out the latter from the former:

```
const rawListOfElements = [...document.querySelectorAll('h4#unique_id ~ h5, h4#unique_id ~ p')];

const elementsToRemove = [...document.querySelectorAll('h4:not(#unique_id) ~ h5, h4:not(#unique_id) ~ p')];

const mySelectedElements = rawListOfElements.filter((element) => elementsToRemove.includes(element) === false).forEach(title => console.log(title));
```

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const rawListOfElements = [...document.querySelectorAll('h4#unique_id ~ h5, h4#unique_id ~ p')];

const elementsToRemove = [...document.querySelectorAll('h4:not(#unique_id) ~ h5, h4:not(#unique_id) ~ p')];

const mySelectedElements = rawListOfElements.filter((element) => elementsToRemove.includes(element) === false).forEach(title => console.log(title));
```

```html
<body>
  <h4 id="unique_id"> foo bing bar </h4>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <!-- selection should start here -->
    <h5>title text 1</h5>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <h5>title text 2</h5>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <h5>title text 3</h5>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
  <!-- and end here -->
  <h4 id="randome_id_234353">title text</h4>
  <p>some text I don't want</p>
  <p>some text I don't want</p>
  <h5>title text I don't want</h5>
  <p>some text I don't want</p>
  <h5>title text I don't want</h5>
  <p>some text I don't want</p>
  <h5>title text I don't want</h5>
  <p>some text I don't want</p>
</body>
```